# Excel - Identify if Worksheet exists between two worksheets?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, worksheet

I have 5 worksheets: (1) Summary (2) 2020 (3) 2019 (4) 2018 (5) 2017

In my "Summary" worksheet, I have Column A with cells each containing the name of each worksheet (A1: 2020, A2: 2019, A3: 2018, A4: 2017) and Column B with the number "1" in each corresponding row.

Let's say I delete the "2019" worksheet so that it is no longer between worksheets "2020" and "2017" - is there any formula that I could use to flag that in row 2? Perhaps through some sort of "if(..,1,0)" formula for Column B? I do not want to use VBA.

Comment: use any formula related to Sheets 2017 - 2020 with IFERROR function, - once sheet deleted, formula will give you error

Comment: example `=IFERROR(SUM('2020'!A1:B1),"Sheet Missing")`

Answer (score 2):

There are various error-checking functions available in Excel, and most of them would be appropriate for your situation. The simplest would be to use IFERROR and just refer to a cell on one of the sheets, like this:

```
=IFERROR('2020'!A1,"Missing")
```

If the formula receives an error value because it can't find the cell, it will display the text "Missing"; otherwise, it will show the value of the cell.

The disadvantage of doing it this way, hard-coding the sheet name into the function, is that if the sheet is deleted the sheet name will be replaced in the formula with #Ref!, so even if the sheet is restored the formula will need to be changed.

We can enhance the functionality by using an INDIRECT along with the IFERROR. This will take a text string and turn it into a cell reference. So assuming we have worksheet names in column A, we could do this:

```
=IFERROR(Indirect(A1 & "!A1"),"Missing")
```

The INDIRECT function takes the *value* in A1 and combines it with the text string, and reads the whole thing as a cell reference. This has the same result, but is more robust since deleting the sheet and then replacing it will clear the error.

For a slightly more elaborate result, we could next IF and ISERROR instead of using IFERROR. It gives us more control over the result.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(A1 & "!A1")),"Missing","Found")
```

ISERROR returns TRUE if the first argument throws an error, an FALSE if it does not. This will return "Found" if the sheet is present, or "Missing" if it isn't.